# PHP function return value, how to check

Tags: php, oop

First a simple example:

```
function doReturnSomething()
{
    // some logic
    if ($resultFromLogic) {
        return Default_Model_Something;
    }

    return false;
}
```

As you can see, this functions returns a model or false. Now, let's call this function from some place else:

```
$something = doReturnSomething();
```

No, I want to put a if-statement to check the variable $something. Let's say:

```
if (false !== $something) {}
```

or

```
if ($something instanceof Default_Model_Something) {}
```

or

```
...
```

Is there a "best practice" for this situation to do? Check for false or use instance of. And are there any consequences for that particular way?

Thank is advance!

Comment: Not directly to the question, but I suggest to return `null` instead of a bollean, because a) `null` is the equivalent of "nothing", which seems to fit here quite well, and b) there may be situations, where the return value should be a boolean and then you cannot distinguish between "nothing" `false` and "value" `false`

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what it is returning, you could just do this:

```
if(doReturnSomething()) {}
```

It will return true when an object is returned (Default_Model_Something) and return false when false is returned or a null-value. Just don't use this way when working with numbers because "0" will evaluate to false.

Comment: This way works well with numbers, as long as (you mentioned it) `0` is not a valid value. For example IDs usually starts with `1`

Comment: That's true. When using instanceof, we can be sure that particular methods / properties are available from the class Default_Model_Something. Are there any disadvantages when using instanceof? If "false !==" a more generic way of typing?

Comment: Hey, sorry if i m getting it wrong, but what if `doReturnSomething()` returns valid model and i have to access it inside `if` braces. it would be better to use it like `$something = doReturnSomething();` and then `if($something){}`

Comment: Yes of course... when you need it on multiple locations you should store it in a variable and check the variable instead. @VincentvanDijk: instanceof also works, but it has limitations in flexibility etc. When you have to depend on certain functions however, I guess it would be best to create some sort of an interface so you can just plugin new classes.

Answer (score 1):

I think that from PHP 5.4 on there is a special notice error for threating a function return in logical statements.

Good pratice is to save result of a function to variable and then use it in any logical statement.

Comment: I don't think there is such a notice. You can try here online: http://codepad.viper-7.com/ - The other part in your answer sounds good IMHO, but maybe you could tell why?

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php function my($a, $b ,$c){

    $total = $a + $b - $c;      return $total;       }

$myNumber = 0;

echo "Before the function, myNumber = ". $myNumber ."<br />";

$myNumber = my(3, 4, 1); // Store the result of mySum in $myNumber

echo "After the function, myNumber = " . $myNumber ."<br />";

?>
```

Comment: What does this have to do with the question asked?