# Getting a contact form to function

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I am trying to get this form to work so people can contact me .... what php or js should I use to make it function? building my website from scratch and want to make sure the contact form is functional . I have added my attempted php code at the bottom. Any help would be appreciated. Are my classes consistent in my php code and css and html? That may be the problem here.

```
here I am adding a contact-form:
        <section id="contact-form">
        <form>
left side of form:
        <div class="contact-left">
        <h1 class="c-l-heading"><font style="border-bottom: 3px solid #1ED98B;">Writ</font>e us</h1>
name:
        <div class="f-name">
        <font >Name</font>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Full Name"/>
        </div>
email:
        <div class="f-email">
        <font >Email</font>
        <input type="email" placeholder="Example@gmail.com"/>
        </div>
        </div>
right:
        <div class="contact-right">
message:
        <div class="message">
        <font >Message</font>
        <textarea name="message" rows="5" cols="20" placeholder="Write Message..."></textarea>
        </div>
submit-btn:
        <button>submit</button>
        </div>
            
        </form>
        </section>
CSS:
    #contact-form{
        width: 100%;
        height: 90vh;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        
    }
    #contact-form form{
        display: flex;
        width: 70%;
        height: 60vh;
        background-color: #1A1A1A;
        box-shadow: 2px 12px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
        border: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.01)
    }
     
    .contact-left{
        width: 40%;
        height: 100%;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
    }
    .contact-right{
        width: 60%;
        height: 100%;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: space-between;
        border-left: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.08);
    }
    .contact-right button{
        width: 100%;
        height: 50px;
        background-color: #1ED98B;
        font-weight: bold;
        outline: none;
        border: none;
        margin: 0px;
        color:#1B1B1B;
        font-size: 14px;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        letter-spacing: 2px;
     
    }
    .c-l-heading{
        font-family: calibri;
        color:#FFFFFF;
        font-size: 3rem;
        letter-spacing: 2px;
        font-weight: 400;
        
    }
    .f-name,.f-email{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        font-family: calibri;
        
    }
    .f-name font,.f-email font{
        color:#BFBFBF;
        font-size: 22px;
    }
    .f-name input,.f-email input{
        height: 30px;
        width:250px;
        border: none;
        outline: none;
        background-color:transparent;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #929292;
        color:#FFFFFF;
        margin: 10px 0px;
    }
    .f-email input::placeholder,
    .f-name input::placeholder{
        opacity: 0.5;
        letter-spacing: 1px;
    }
    .f-email input:focus,
    .f-name input:focus{
        border-bottom: 1px solid #17d1ac;
        transition: all ease 0.5s;
    }.message font{
        font-size: 18px;
        color:#4E4E4E;
        font-family: calibri;
        
    }
    .message{
        margin: 20px;
    }
    .contact-right textarea{
        width: 100% !important;
        height: 320px !important;
        border: none;
        outline: none;
        background-color:transparent;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        color:#EBEBEB;
        font-size: 16px;
    }
    .contact-right textarea::placeholder{
        color:#EBEBEB;
        font-size: 18px;
        letter-spacing: 2px;
        font-family: calibri;
    }
    .contact-right button:active{
        transform: scale(1.04);
        transition: all ease 0.1s;
    }

Thanks in advance for your time!
```

here is my php code:

```
?php
    $name = $_POST['name']; /*this will display the name of the users */
    $visitor_email = $_Post['email']; /*this will display the email of the user */
    $message = $_POST['message']; /*this will store the message */


    $email_from = 'Exampleemail@.com' /*I will receive this via this line of code */

    $email_subject = "new form submission";

    $email_body = "User Name: $name.\n"."User Email: $visitor_email.\n"."User Message: $message.\n";




    $to = "Exampleemail@.com";
    $headers = "From: $email_from\r\n";
    mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);

    header("Location:index.html");
```

Comment: `$to = "Exampleemail@.com";` - are you actually running your code with this value, or did you just change this in the question to hide your real e-mail address?

Comment: @EI_Vanja -That is correct. It is for security purposes . In real life it will be my email address.

Comment: Alright. Now, your first step is to check the return value of the `mail` function to see if php successfully passed the message on to the mail server. If it returns `true`, then the problem is not in your code.

Comment: @El-Vanja How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Looks like you should be going through a PHP tutorial to learn the basics. Here's a [quick read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8880060/php-function-return-value-how-to-check).

Answer (score 0):

For a simple email service, try https://www.smtpjs.com/. It allows you to create a free account and set up a mail server with them. Make sure to use a secure key in it however, unless you want others to see your password (available in website for free). One downside is the 500/day limit and your email is visible to users with a simple inspect.